# Forcing users to change his password at next login using puppet

Tags: puppet

I am using `users' resource to create unix accounts and then set a default password. For this I have written the following manifest .

```
node 'node2.example.com','node3.example.com'{
 user {
      'askar':
       ensure  => 'present',
       managehome => 'true',
       comment => 'man Home',
       home    => '/home/askar',
       shell   => '/bin/bash',
       expiry  => '2016-03-22',
       password => '$1$cs1j/t.D$4Q2Ocr0pulyNTUx/',
       password_min_age => '30',
       password_max_age => '60',
      }
   }
```

It works fine, but I want the user should be forced to change his password at next login. For this I extended the rule with an exec resource to run the following command `chage -d 0 askar` so that the user is forced to change the password

```
exec {
          'chage':
          command => 'chage -d 0 askar'
     }
   }
```

But this is not working for me. Can you please suggest how can I get a user forced to change his password at next login .

Answer (score 1):

If you specify a `password` in a user resource, puppet will clobber the user's password. You're telling puppet to set the user's password hash to the value in your post, and it will continue overwriting that data on every run if the user changes it. Your minimum age setting also implies a user cannot change their password for 30 days after setting it, which may contribute to your problem.

http://www.joseftschiggerl.name/2012/11/create-users-with-puppet/ suggests a distro-dependent action:

```
case $::osfamily {
        RedHat: {$action = "/bin/sed -i -e 's/$id:!!:/$id:$pass:/g' /etc/shadow; chage -d 0 $id"}
        Debian: {$action = "/bin/sed -i -e 's/$id:x:/$id:$pass:/g' /etc/shadow; chage -d 0 $id"}
}
```

But honestly, if these are user accounts and not service accounts, you'd likely be much happier just setting up an LDAP server that handles password aging and complexity centrally, instead of having to manage multiple users with different passwords on every box.

Comment: Is it not possible to disable a puppet manifest so that  agents does not read it further .

Comment: Not really, no. You can do some things with `refreshonly` to make a resource only run when some other resource is updated, but this is a problem best solved with LDAP, not with puppet.

Answer (score 0):

This was already answered [here](https://ask.puppetlabs.com/question/25107/forcing-user-to-change-his-unix-login-password/).